# Why is Yii2 framework showing a 404 error when creating custom view page?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm attempting to create a custom display in yii2 framework using this code in my site controller:

```
/******/
public function actionChartDisplay()
{
    return $this->render('chartDisplay');
}
```

for testing purposes I pasted the form name in my actionAbout function as a parameter to the render function in it. It worked with this:

```
public function actionAbout()
{
    return $this->render('chartDisplay');
}
```

But I need to create many custom views in yii2 and this won't be a solution.

This is the error I get[image]

I'm curious as to why it is. Since I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTO1nwLeEbk) tutorial and came across this weird behaviour.
My 'chartDisplay.php' file is merely a "hello world" that does work with the action about function.

Comment: add screenshot of error you see on screen

Comment: @ParitoshMahale Done :)

Comment: like my answer said, the request has to be `chart-display`, not `chartDisplay`

Comment: the error message is related  to the chartForm view  ...  update you question and add  your real  controller/action code  ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in yii2, the controllers and actions with multiple words, that are marked by capital letters are divided by `-` in your request, so in your case the route would be `some/chart-display`

Comment: I tried using chart-display however I got a php syntax error so I changed it to a simple "chart" name, it seems this controllers are case-sensitive thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently as @SmartCoder pointed out it was an error on how Yii2 Handles the action functions in its controller however I didn't mark his answer as the solution right away because implementing it resulted in an error. So aside from that I'm posting the way I solved it.

So instead of using chart-display I simply changed it for "charts" like this:

```
public function actionCharts(){
    return $this->render('charts');
}
```

Changed the name of my file so it fits to `charts.php` and it worked.